# Why both template functions and overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, function-templates

So I'm kind of new to C++ and I just started learning about template functions.  After learning about them, I must ask the question:  Why does C++ allow you to overload functions that are not methods when template functions exist?  It almost seems redundant when looking at the fact that template functions can be used as many times as the programmer needs with whatever data type the programmer wants.

Comment: Actually, typical C++ practice is to [prefer overloading freestanding functions instead of specializing template functions](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: Sometimes you only want to support certain datatypes or you can/want only guarantee the correctness for certain combination of parameter types, you could enforce this using some checks of the template arguments but this might become unreadable.